# Find the most recent record from the table for the given criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

It may seem like a duplicate question, but all the answers I found on SO didn't help me solve this.

So, I have this database that stores every update on an item. Essentially, when the item is first created, the `statusId` is 1 and the date it's created. If someone updated the item and changed the status of the item, the `statusId` for that item is added. For eg. a new row with `statusId` 2 is added with the current date. And so on and so forth. One example of the table is shown below:

```
id  statusId    updatedDate             userId  authId
1   1           2016-12-20 15:43:17.703 14      14
2   1           2016-12-20 15:54:01.523 14      15
3   2           2016-12-21 16:05:48.157 14      14
4   3           2016-12-21 16:27:58.610 14      15
5   1           2016-12-20 17:16:47.627 14      18
6   1           2016-12-20 17:27:58.930 14      19
7   1           2017-01-18 14:13:35.800 18      20
```

So, what I want to do next is query the table where the most recent `statusId` is given. For the table above, the query for `statusid` = 1 should show the following result:

```
id  statusId    updatedDate             userId  authId
5   1           2016-12-20 17:16:47.627 14      18
6   1           2016-12-20 17:27:58.930 14      19
7   1           2017-01-18 14:13:35.800 18      20
```

Notice how the list doesn't show for authIds 14 and 15 even though it has status 1 but have different statusId in the later date.

One way I tried doing is the following:

```
select A1.id, A1.statusId, A1.updatedDate, A1.userId, A1.authId from AuthProgressTracker A1
    left join AuthProgressTracker A2
    on (A1.authId = A2.authId and A1.updatedDate > A2.updatedDate)
    where A2.authId is not null
```

That didn't show the result I was looking for. I tried another one

```
SELECT *
    FROM AuthProgressTracker T
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT id, authId, statusId, MAX(updatedDate) as maxDate FROM AuthProgressTracker GROUP BY authId, statusId, id
        ) AP 
        ON AP.id = T.id AND T.updatedDate = AP.maxDate 
        order by T.id
```

This didn't produce the desired result either.

What am I missing?

And how can I break down the problems in SQL Server 2012 so that I can learn to figure out the problems like this in the future?

Comment: You should tell us what version of SQL you are using.

Comment: Why don't you include rows with `id in (3,4)`? Those are the most recent status updates for `AuthId`s 14 and 15.

Comment: Sorry. I thought I added the version. It escaped my mind somehow. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem statement may have lead you a bit astray, because while you want the most recent records, the timestamp may not be how you arrive at your result set.  In the query below, I use a subquery which identifies all `authId` which do *not* have a `statusId` other than `1`.  This then filters the original table to leave you with the results you want.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM AuthProgressTracker t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT authId
    FROM AuthProgressTracker
    GROUP BY authId
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN statusId <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
) t2
    ON t1.authId = t2.authId
```

Answer (score 0):

(You haven't stated what RDBMS you're using, so you'll need to adjust your queries accordingly. E.g. If using mysql, use `LIMIT` syntax instead of `TOP`.)

```
declare @AuthProgressTracker table (
    id int,
    statusId int,
    updatedDate datetime,
    userId int,
    authId int
)
insert into @AuthProgressTracker
values 
(1,   1,           '2016-12-20 15:43:17.703', 14,      14),
(2,   1,           '2016-12-20 15:54:01.523', 14,      15),
(3,   2,           '2016-12-21 16:05:48.157', 14,      14),
(4,   3,           '2016-12-21 16:27:58.610', 14,      15),
(5,   1,           '2016-12-20 17:16:47.627', 14,      18),
(6,   1,           '2016-12-20 17:27:58.930', 14,      19),
(7,   1,           '2017-01-18 14:13:35.800', 18,      20)


/* Determine id's of latest status updates per authId */
SELECT  MAX(id) as LatestSatus
FROM    @AuthProgressTracker
GROUP BY authId

/* Note the above includes row id's you've chosen to exclude, so... */
/* Determine most recent statusId */
SELECT  TOP 1 statusId
FROM    @AuthProgressTracker
ORDER BY updatedDate DESC

/* Putting it all together */
SELECT  i.*
FROM    @AuthProgressTrackeri
        INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  MAX(id) as LatestSatus
        FROM    @AuthProgressTracker
        GROUP BY authId
        ) ls ON
            ls.LatestSatus = i.id
WHERE   i.statusId = (
        SELECT  TOP 1 statusId
        FROM    @AuthProgressTracker
        ORDER BY updatedDate DESC
        )
```